# DevExpress Gridview - different datasource on column in display mode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

i work with Gridview Devexpress components, a have little problem with it. I try description my problem.

I have diffedent data source for column "Format" dependent on column Typ, in edit mode its ok show good data source

Image: http://www.imageshack.cz/images/2015/01/11/obr2.png

But if i save it and want show selected "Formát" in display mode, i get only one datasource, which was declaration on column "Formát" on init as here in code.

Look on column "Formát" its bad variable because in display mode i have only one datasource

Image: http://www.imageshack.cz/images/2015/01/11/obr3.png

```
settings.Columns.Add(column =>
            {
                column.FieldName = "FormatType";
                column.Caption = Resources.FormatType;

                column.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.ComboBox;
                var comboBoxProperties = column.PropertiesEdit as ComboBoxProperties;
                comboBoxProperties.DataSource = WebApp.Helpers.CodebooksHelper.GetItemData(1);
                comboBoxProperties.TextField = "Title";
                comboBoxProperties.ValueField = "ItemID";
                comboBoxProperties.ValueType = typeof(int);
                comboBoxProperties.IncrementalFilteringMode =IncrementalFilteringMode.StartsWith;
                comboBoxProperties.DropDownStyle = DropDownStyle.DropDownList;
            });
```

Exist something, where i can declare datasource on column in display mode as edit mode?

```
 settings.CellEditorInitialize
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [ASPxGridView.CustomColumnDisplayText](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridView_CustomColumnDisplayTexttopic) event.

```
protected void ASPxGridView2_CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender,
    DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridViewColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Column.FieldName != "FormatType") return;
    e.DisplayText = WebApp.Helpers.CodebooksHelper.GetItemData(1).First(item => item.ItemID == (int)e.Value).Title;
}

settings.CustomColumnDisplayText += (sender, e) => {
        if (e.Column.FieldName != "FormatType") return;
        e.DisplayText = WebApp.Helpers.CodebooksHelper.GetItemData(1).First(item => item.ItemID == (int)e.Value).Title;
}
```